# How does the assignment operator work on elements of a 2D character array?

Tags: c

For the below code snippet, I am not getting how can we assign a value to 
`names[1][2]` since it returns the address of the 2nd column in Row 1. How can we assign `names[2][1]`?

Which returns address of column 1 in Row 2 to `names[1][2]`?

I am unable to get how can one column address can be stored in another column address.

What is the significance of the statement?

> ```
> names[1][2]=names[2][1] ;   // what is it doing
> ```

```
int main() {
    char names[3][20] = { "success", "gateway", "engineers" };
    int i;
    char *t;

    t = names[1][2];
    names[1][2] = names[2][1];
    names[2][1] = t;

    for (i = 0; i <= 2; i++)
        printf("%s  ", names[i]);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Heed your compiler warnings — when the compiler deigns to warn you about something in your code, it means your code is wrong; your code has a bug.  Just because the compiler doesn't warn you doesn't mean your code is right, but if the compiler does warn, it means you have a bug egregious enough that it tells you about it.  You can assume the compiler is perfect — it is incredibly unlikely you'll find a compiler bug in programs you're writing.  Remember: the compiler knows a lot more about C than you do!

Comment: Also, it is a good idea to ensure that output ends with a newline.  It means that the output is more likely to appear on your screen in a timely fashion, for example.

Comment: Given `int i = 1; int j = 2; i = j;`, the assignment actually copies the value from the address identified by `j` into the address identified by `i`.  There's not much difference when the assignment is `names[1][2] = names[2][1];` instead.  Yes, the `l-value` (on the left-hand side or LHS of the assignment) is more complex, and the `r-value` (on the right-hand side or RHS of the assignment) is more complex, but the concept is the same.  On the LHS, the value is assigned to the identified location; on the RHS, the value is collected from the identified location.

Answer (score 0):

> "how can we assign names[2][1] which returns address of column 1 in Row 2 to names[1][2]"

`names[2][1]` does not return the address, it gives the 2nd character in the 3rd string (because of zero indexing).

`name[2][1]` in this case is the character `n`.

So, `names[1][2]=names[2][1]` is basically assigning `names[1][2]` with the character at `names[2][1]`.

Answer (score 0):

`names[x][y]` is not an address.
`names` is a matrix in which each cell is a character, so first row contains characters  
 `'s','u','c','c','e','s','s'` in the first seven columns ( and so on for other rows). 
The statement

```
names[1][2]=names[2][1] ;
```

means that you're assigning at the cell at index (1,2) the value of the cell at index (2,1), in your case you're editing third character of second word, from "ga*t*eway" to "ga*n*eway"

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you merely exchange the third character of the second line and the second character of the third line, and you are using an incorrect type `char *t` to hold the value.

If you mean to exchange 2 lines, you should use an array of pointers to strings:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char *names[3] = { "success", "gateway", "engineers" };
    int i;
    char *t;

    t = names[1];
    names[1] = names[2];
    names[2] = t;

    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        printf("%s ", names[i]);
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```